# Gluon Client Maven Plugin - Resource filtering isn't working on 'client:package'

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, javafx-11

I am working on a javafx 11 mobile project and Gluon client plugin is being used to build APK.

From this single project we need to build multiple apps (APKs) for different customers. I've done that using maven profiles.

Now I am trying to update 'AndroidManifest.xml' dynamically to set different **package name** for each builds. I've tried maven resource filtering to update that property dynamically. It's not working as expected.

Below is the 'AndroidManifest.xml' (in src/android):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<manifest xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
    package='${app.package.name}'
    android:versionCode='${app.version.code}'
    android:versionName='${app.version.name}'>
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application android:label="${app.name}" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name='com.gluonhq.helloandroid.MainActivity' android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
         <intent-filter>
            <category android:name='android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'/>
            <action android:name='android.intent.action.MAIN'/>
         </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name='com.gluonhq.helloandroid.PermissionRequestActivity'/>
</application>
```

As you can see above, **package**, **versionCode**, **versionName** and **appLabel** are defined as filter variables.

Below is the manifest in "target\classes" after executing **mvn client:build -P android** command.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<manifest xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
    package='com.company.parent.app'
    android:versionCode='1'
    android:versionName='1.0'>
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application android:label="CB Parents" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name='com.gluonhq.helloandroid.MainActivity' android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
         <intent-filter>
            <category android:name='android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'/>
            <action android:name='android.intent.action.MAIN'/>
         </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name='com.gluonhq.helloandroid.PermissionRequestActivity'/>
</application>
```

Below is the manifest in "target\client\aarch64-android\gvm\android_project\app\src\main" after executing **mvn client:package -P android** command.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<manifest xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
    package='${app.package.name}'
    android:versionCode='${app.version.code}'
    android:versionName='${app.version.name}'>
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application android:label="${app.name}" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name='com.gluonhq.helloandroid.MainActivity' android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
         <intent-filter>
            <category android:name='android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'/>
            <action android:name='android.intent.action.MAIN'/>
         </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name='com.gluonhq.helloandroid.PermissionRequestActivity'/>
</application>
```

Because the filters are not applied as expected, the 'mvn client:package -P android' task fails.

Below is how I applied filtering for AndroidManifest in **pom.xml**.

```
<!-- To set AndroidManifest properties dynamically -->
  <resource>
    <directory>src/android</directory>
    <!-- Map ${} into resources -->
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>AndroidManifest.xml</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
```

Why is filtering not working only with 'mvn client:package' task while it works with 'mvn client:build' task? or Am I missing anything?

PS. It's also possible to update 'appLabel', 'versionCode' and 'versionName' through client plugin configuration. But I want to keep every dynamic properties in a single properties file. And also there's no option to set 'packageName' through that plugin. That's why I am updating them through resource filtering.

Update #1: Here is my pom.xml. It's not polished yet.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>multi-profile-project3</groupId>
  <artifactId>multi-profile-project3</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <main.class>com.multiprofile.app.main.Main</main.class>
    </properties>

  <build>
  
    <!-- Loading all ${} -->
    <filters>
      <filter>src/${env}/resources/application-${env}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    
    <resources>
      <!-- Loading fxml and css (under 'main' directory) -->
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>

      <!-- Loading main resources -->
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <!-- Map ${} into resources -->
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>*.properties</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>

      <!-- Loading school specific resources based on 'env' -->
      <resource>
        <directory>src/${env}/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>

      <!-- To set AndroidManifest properties dynamically -->
      <resource>
        <directory>src/android</directory>
        <!-- Map ${} into resources -->
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>AndroidManifest.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

<!-- Copy images from src/{env}/resources/images/android_res
                 to src/android/res -->
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
         <executions>
           <execution>
            <id>id.initresources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>

           <execution>
             <id>copy-resources</id>
             <phase>validate</phase>
             <goals>
               <goal>copy-resources</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
               <outputDirectory>src/android/res</outputDirectory>
               <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/${env}/resources/images/android_res</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>
             </configuration>
           </execution>
         </executions>       
      </plugin>
    
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

        <!-- To load properties from '.properties' file and use them as a property -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>id.validateprops</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <files>
                    <file>src/${env}/resources/application-${env}.properties</file>
                  </files>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              
              <execution>
                  <id>id.outputprops</id>
                  <phase>generate-resources</phase> 
                  <goals> 
                      <goal>write-project-properties</goal> 
                  </goals> 
                  <configuration> 
                      <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/properties-from-pom.properties</outputFile> 
                  </configuration> 
              </execution>            
            </executions>
          </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.36</version>
        <configuration>
            <target>${client.target}</target>
            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
            <reflectionList>
              <list>com.multiprofile.app.login.LoginPresenter</list>
            </reflectionList>
            <bundlesList>
              <list>application</list>
            </bundlesList>
            <releaseConfiguration>
            </releaseConfiguration>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    
    <profile>
      <id>school1</id>
      <properties>
        <env>school1</env>
      </properties>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
    </profile>
    
    <profile>
      <id>school2</id>
      <properties>
        <env>school2</env>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    
    <profile>
      <id>school3</id>
      <properties>
        <env>school3</env>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <!-- Profile for android build -->
    <profile>
      <id>android</id>
      <properties>
        <client.target>android</client.target>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <!-- Profile for ios build -->
    <profile>
      <id>ios</id>
      <properties>
        <client.target>ios</client.target>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.airhacks</groupId>
      <artifactId>afterburner.fx</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

So, there are profiles for **android**, **ios** and for **each schools**. I use following maven commands for building and packaging "**mvn client:build -P school1,android**", "**mvn client:package -P school1,android**" respectively.

Comment: If I get it right, you have a plugin in your pom, that is invoked with the build command, and it creates a correct AndroidManifest.xml under `target/classes`. The problem with that approach is that client:package is not looking for that file in target, but in `src/android`. Are you able to replace that file directly in `src/android`? Would be great if you could post your pom.

Comment: The plugin is [Maven Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). I am not actually creating or replacing entire manifest file on the fly. I'll only update existing manifest which is already in `src/android` by replacing the filter placeholders with values by using that plugin. I've updated the pom file in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but as I said before, Client plugin doesn't look into `target/classes` but only into `src/android` for the Android manifest. Maybe you can try with [`copy-resources`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Now I have separate manifest files for each schools under `src/school` directory. I've configured maven-resources-plugin to copy it into 'src/android' based on activated profile. But the problem is, I have to manually delete the copied 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml' before committing it into git. Are there any better approaches to handle this situation?

Comment: Maybe you can create a dummy profile that just copies the original manifest on top of the last one, after you have run all the real profiles?

Comment: Or simply add the copied `AndroidManifest.xml` to `.gitignore` that should be sufficient.